# Pandas PeriodIndex boolean slice returning entire index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the last viable date in a multi-index dataframe:

```
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["a"], pd.PeriodIndex(start="2017-01", end="2017-03")])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[0,1, np.nan], index=ix, columns=["test"])
df # outputs
            test
a   2017-01 0.0
    2017-02 1.0
    2017-03 NaN
```

So far so good, but slicing this and returning the last returns the entire index:

```
df.loc[df["test"].notnull(), "test"].index
MultiIndex(levels=[['a'], [2017-01, 2017-02, 2017-03]], labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])
```

My thinking is this should return an array where `.index.levels[1][-1]` last element is something like `Period('2017-02')`?

Comment: `df.last_valid_index()`?

Comment: @ayhan Nice! Learned something. Will you write an answer?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It seemed the example might be this way just for the sake of creating a MCVE and the actual problem was keeping the unused indices.  Feel free to mention that in your answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it should, and you can make it do that if you so wish, using [`remove_unused_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html) -

```
i = df.loc[df["test"].notnull(), "test"]
i.index = i.index.remove_unused_levels()
```

```
i.index
MultiIndex(levels=[['a'], [2017-01, 2017-02]],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])
```

This function removes those levels which do not actually exist in the current dataframe slice.

---

Alternatively, you can view the current values in the `index` by querying the `values` attribute -

```
i.index.values
array([('a', Period('2017-01', 'M')), ('a', Period('2017-02', 'M'))], dtype=object)
```

---

If it's just the last valid index you want (as your question hinted as such), then you can use [@ayhan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028092/pandas-periodindex-boolean-slice-returning-entire-index?noredirect=1#comment83026257_48028092): `last_valid_index` -

```
i.last_valid_index()
('a', Period('2017-02', 'M'))
```

It has a sister function, `first_valid_index` -

```
i.first_valid_index()
('a', Period('2017-01', 'M'))
```

There's not much more use to these functions besides querying these two values.

Comment: Seems strange not to do this automatically.  Thank you!

Comment: @Tony Indeed, but I'm sure there's a good reason for it. Next time I see Andy or Jeff, I'll ask them :-)

Comment: For this problem, I went with @ayhan's answer just because I needed the last one.  But your earlier answer addressed my next question which was going to be passing this index into another dataframe.  You both rock.

Comment: @Tony Ah, now I feel a bit down using ayhan's answer. Well, I'll delete if he asks me to! Anyway, that's nothing for you to worry about, so happy coding!

Comment: I'm getting a bit tired of trying to get through numpy/pandas through watching the tags. Is there a cheatsheet you guys are actually using or are you genuinely remembering these 100's (if not 1000's) of methods?

Comment: @roganjosh I wish I had good news for you. But I learned the hard way: watching all my subpar answers lose to piRSquared and jezrael. :p

Comment: That's fair enough :) I just feel like every time I learn a combination of methods that might do what I want, I then stumble over a single method that does it all. I'll play catch-up, thanks for teaching me a new one :)